# Spring Integration - placeholders not injected into ws:outbound-gateway uri (only for unit tests)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-integration

I wrote some Spring Integration flow which effectively calls some external WebService. ws:outbound-gateway uri of mentioned WS is configured via property placeholders and that works perfectly well when running full application context. Properties are configured in Spring Boot's `application.properties`.

Now when I try to write an integration test which calls Gateway (BigService) it fails with `IllegalArgumentException: Map has no value for 'adapter.icc.big.srv.protocol'`. Exception is thrown when calling Gateway method (`BigService#invoke`)
So it looks like `application.properties` are not read but when I inspect `Environment` in test context everything looks fine.

Please find the most important code snippets bellow.

```
// part of int-big-conf.xml
<int:chain input-channel="adapter.big.inputChannel" output-channel="adapter.big.outputChannel">
  <int-ws:outbound-gateway  id="bigVerificationGateway"
     uri="${adapter.icc.big.srv.protocol}://${adapter.icc.big.srv.host}:${adapter.icc.big.srv.port}/${adapter.icc.big.srv.context}"
     marshaller="bigMarshaller" unmarshaller="bigMarshaller" />
</int:chain>

// configuration class (full)
@Configuration
@ImportResource("classpath:int/big/int-big-conf.xml")
@ComponentScan("pl.orange.opl.cv.integration.big")
public class BigIntegrationConfiguration {

   @Bean(name = "inputValidator")
   public Validator inputValidator(){
       return new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
   }
}

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = {BigIntegrationConfiguration.class})
public class BigTest {

    @Autowired
    private BigService bigService;

    @Test
    public void testVerificationNegative() throws IOException {
        ....
        BIGIntegrationResponseDTO invoke = bigService.invoke(bigRequestDTO);
        ....
    }
```

Technology stack:
- Spring Boot 1.3.0
- Spring Integration 4.2.1
- Spring 4.2.3

Any idea what I am doing wrong? Thanks in advance

Full stack trace:

```
org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: error occurred in message handler [org.springframework.integration.handler.MessageHandlerChain#0$child.bigVerificationGateway.handler]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Map has no value for 'adapter.icc.big.srv.protocol'
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:139)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.MessageHandlerChain$1.send(MessageHandlerChain.java:123)
at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:115)
at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:45)
at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:105)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:231)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.produceOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:154)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutputs(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:102)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:105)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:127)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.MessageHandlerChain$1.send(MessageHandlerChain.java:123)
at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:115)
at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:45)
at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:105)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:231)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.produceOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:154)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutputs(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:102)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:105)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:127)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.MessageHandlerChain$1.send(MessageHandlerChain.java:123)
at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:115)
at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:45)
at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:105)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:231)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.produceOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:154)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutputs(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:102)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:105)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:127)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.MessageHandlerChain.handleMessageInternal(MessageHandlerChain.java:104)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:127)
at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:116)
at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:147)
at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:120)
at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:77)
at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:442)
at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:392)
at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:115)
at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSendAndReceive(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:150)
at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSendAndReceive(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:45)
at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessagingTemplate.sendAndReceive(AbstractMessagingTemplate.java:42)
at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.sendAndReceive(MessagingTemplate.java:97)
at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.sendAndReceive(MessagingTemplate.java:38)
at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessagingTemplate.convertSendAndReceive(AbstractMessagingTemplate.java:79)
at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessagingTemplate.convertSendAndReceive(AbstractMessagingTemplate.java:70)
at org.springframework.integration.gateway.MessagingGatewaySupport.doSendAndReceive(MessagingGatewaySupport.java:412)
at org.springframework.integration.gateway.MessagingGatewaySupport.sendAndReceive(MessagingGatewaySupport.java:386)
at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean.invokeGatewayMethod(GatewayProxyFactoryBean.java:422)
at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean.doInvoke(GatewayProxyFactoryBean.java:382)
at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean.invoke(GatewayProxyFactoryBean.java:373)
at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayCompletableFutureProxyFactoryBean.invoke(GatewayCompletableFutureProxyFactoryBean.java:64)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy38.invoke(Unknown Source)
at pl.orange.opl.cv.integration.big.BigTest.testVerificationNegative(BigTest.java:76)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:254)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:89)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:193)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:117)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:234)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:74)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Map has no value for 'adapter.icc.big.srv.protocol'
at org.springframework.web.util.UriComponents$MapTemplateVariables.getValue(UriComponents.java:306)
at org.springframework.web.util.UriComponents.expandUriComponent(UriComponents.java:230)
at org.springframework.web.util.HierarchicalUriComponents.expandInternal(HierarchicalUriComponents.java:324)
at org.springframework.web.util.HierarchicalUriComponents.expandInternal(HierarchicalUriComponents.java:47)
at org.springframework.web.util.UriComponents.expand(UriComponents.java:152)
at org.springframework.web.util.UriComponentsBuilder.buildAndExpand(UriComponentsBuilder.java:401)
at org.springframework.integration.ws.AbstractWebServiceOutboundGateway.prepareUri(AbstractWebServiceOutboundGateway.java:209)
at org.springframework.integration.ws.AbstractWebServiceOutboundGateway.handleRequestMessage(AbstractWebServiceOutboundGateway.java:179)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:99)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:127)
```

Comment: I don't see a property `adapter.icc.big.srv.protocol` anywhere in that configuration; also please edit the question to show the full stack trace for the IllegalArgumentException.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `@IntegrationTest` alongside with the `@SpringApplicationConfiguration`:

```
* Test class annotation signifying that the tests are "integration tests" and therefore
 * require full startup in the same way as a production application. Normally used in
 * conjunction with {@code @SpringApplicationConfiguration}.
 * <p>
 * If your test also uses {@code @WebAppConfiguration} consider using the
 * {@link WebIntegrationTest} instead.
```

The `@EnableAutoConfiguration` should not be presented there at all. It is responsibility of your tarter `BigIntegrationConfiguration`.

And yes, we don't see any property placeholders in your configuration.

**UPDATE**

> That is why I have added @EnableAutoConfiguration on BigTest but it simply does not work.

Yes, that's true: it doesn't. And it is just because the test class isn't a bean in the application context `DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener`:

```
protected void injectDependencies(final TestContext testContext) throws Exception {
    Object bean = testContext.getTestInstance();
    AutowireCapableBeanFactory beanFactory = testContext.getApplicationContext().getAutowireCapableBeanFactory();
    beanFactory.autowireBeanProperties(bean, AutowireCapableBeanFactory.AUTOWIRE_NO, false);
    beanFactory.initializeBean(bean, testContext.getTestClass().getName());
    testContext.removeAttribute(REINJECT_DEPENDENCIES_ATTRIBUTE);
}
```

As you see `testInstance` isn't registered as a bean, although it is affected by the autowiring mechanism.

To achieve your `part/module of bigger application` requirements and still have `@EnableAutoConfiguration`/`@SpringBootApplication` you should just have some fake internal `@Configuration` for the test and `@Import` your partial main config:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = ContextConfiguration.class)
@DirtiesContext
public abstract class MyTests {

    @SpringBootApplication
    @Import(BigIntegrationConfiguration.class)
    public static class ContextConfiguration {

    }

}
```

Comment: Hmm, I did what you have suggested: on `BigTest` class I have added `@IntegrationTest` and removed `@EnableAutoConfiguration`
and on `BigIntegrationConfiguration` I added `@EnableAutoConfiguration`

...and it works. What really helped was the second. I did not annotate `BigIntegrationConfiguration` with auto-configuration before because it is part/module of bigger application and I thought it would be redundant (as whole application starter class is already annotated with `@EnableAutoConfiguration`).
That is why I have added `@EnableAutoConfiguration` on `BigTest` but it simply does not work.

Comment: Well, with auto-configuration enabled on `BigIntegrationConfiguration` class I do not even need to annotate test class with `@IntegrationTest`.  
Generally I am glad it finally works but on the other hand I feel something is wrong here. Modifying code that is under testing just to pass test configuration requirements does not seem to be the best way to achieve the green.  
So, is there something wrong with assumptions I made or the issue is "on Spring side"?

Comment: Understood. Works like a charm. Thanks Artem!